# Add Thread.Sleep time inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my application I am showing/hide footer when the user touch the screen. So when the user touch the screen footer gets visible and after 5 seconds the footer hides automatically. To wait for 5 seconds I am using Thread.Sleep inside a AsyncTask so that the UI don't get freeze.

```
if (!IsShowing) {
            footer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            IsShowing = true;

            WaitInThread wait = new WaitInThread(ViewChartActivity.this);
            wait.execute(5000);
        }
```

Below is the code for WaitInThread class implementing AsyncTask.

```
public class WaitInThread extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Boolean> {

private Activity activity;
private AsynWaitThread callback;

public WaitInThread(Activity _activity) {
    this.activity = _activity;
    this.callback = (AsynWaitThread) activity;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... arg0) {
    try {
        synchronized(this) {
            Thread.sleep(arg0[0]); // LOCK is held
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    try {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        callback.onWaitComplete();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Currently the footer is showed on Touch and it is hidden automatically after 5 seconds. What I want to achieve is to increase the Thread sleep time. So lets say user touch the screen and Thread is sleep inside AsyncTask so if the user again touches the screen before 5 seconds then 5 seconds should be added to the Sleep time which is currently not. I hope that I am able to explain what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Add a variable called time, like int time = 5000;
And at: wait.execute(time);
And in the onPostExecute do:
time += 5000;

Comment: If I increment the time valu in onPostExecute then will the thread remain sleep? Because onPostExecute is called after doInBackground is completed?

Comment: Yes, onPostExecute is called after the doInBackground, so in the next time that the user clicks the screen the time will have more 5 seconds, is that what you want?

Comment: No. I want it to be different. When the user will touch the screen it will be checked if the Thread is still sleeping in the AsyncTask. If the Thread is still sleeping then 5 more seconds will be added to it. If the the Thread is not sleeping and AsyncTask is finished or never started the AsyncTask will be started and Thread will sleep for 5 seconds.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to achieve is not possible through my current approach because AsyncTask executes only once and for my approach to work same AsyncTask has to be executed several time but checking it states. Guess no body every wanted to do this :(